# Why Does Visual Studio Give the Warning "Relational Expression As Switch Expression"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

I have the following code:

```
float x = 0.43;
float y = 1.56;
size_t largerValueIndex = 1;
size_t smallerValueIndex = 0;
switch (x > y) {
case 1:
    largerValueIndex = 0;
    smallerValueIndex = 1;
    break;
}
```

Visual Studio issues the warning "C4144: '>': relational expression as switch statement".

What I'd like to know is why is the warning necessary?  I was under the impression that most switch and if statements are comparisons between two values.  Is this considered bad practice?  And if so, why?

My question has to do with the value being used as the switch expression, not those in the cases.

Comment: `switch` is often more than two, but the compiler is trying to tell you you have defined `if`-like behaviour in a `switch`, and this is weird-enough that it should be pointed out. More often than not, you'd find this to be a mistake that needs fixing.

Comment: (x > y) only has the values true and false.  The normal use of switch is something like `switch (x) { case 1: .....   case 2: ....` -- not a comparison between 2+ variables, it is a list of values for x.   Also, for only 2 values, here true and false, if...else is more clear.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that I understand.  Are you saying that an if statement would be more efficient here?

Comment: Why not just `size_t largerValueIndex = y > x; size_t smallerValueIndex = !largerValueIndex;`

Comment: That's also a good point...

Comment: @paddy - I'd be afraid than boolean true might not be == 1 for some compiler, but I haven't checked C++ language spec to see if it is or not.

Comment: @DaveS spec says you'll get 1 for true, but I can't find where [conv.integral] got off to in [this monster](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/)

Comment: @DaveS The language defines the result of reinterpreting a boolean `true` value as an integer to be equal to 1 for quite some time now. Only extremely old compilers would have a problem.

Comment: Anyways @Dave S if you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.  Thanks again.

Comment: [Found it!](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.integral#2): *If the destination type is `bool`, see [\[conv.bool\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.bool). If the source type is `bool`, the value `false` is converted to zero and the `value` true is converted to one.* This goes back at least to C++11.

Comment: Speed-wise, probably no difference by the time the compiler's done. But this just looks weird and you'd have folk tripping over it, wondering what the <expletive deleted> you were thinking, and possibly inserting bugs in the code during maintenance as a result because that's what confused people do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `(x >y)` evaluates to boolean true and false, which convert to 0 and 1 as noted by @paddy and @user4581301 (see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv.integral#2)

While `switch ( -relational expression- )` is legal, is is not normally used because there are only two values and `if ( expression ) { ...true code... } else { ...false code... }` is easier to understand.

switch is normally used for one integer variable or expression to efficiently list the expected values instead of a long chain of `if...else if...else if...else`

Answer (score 1):

Although the code is correct,  `switch` is normally used for scenarios with more than two possible outcomes; a test with only two possible outcomes should be an `if`.

The compiler warns about this because the unexpected use of `switch` might indicate a typo or a logic error.